# Data Verification in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I am in the last course I will have for COBOL in college, and I have to write interacting programs that are supposed to keep track of inventory for a business. I have reached a few parts that I am having problems with. The first is verifying that the date is between the years 2011 and 2012, and the second is that the month and day numbers are between 1-12 and 1-31, respectively. When I run my program, it always says in the error report that the year is wrong, even when I put it in right. Here is my code for that part:

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       05  POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S.
           10 POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-1  PIC XX.
           10 POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-2  PIC XX.
           10 POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-3  PIC XX.
           10 POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-4  PIC XX.

   SCREEN SECTION.
   01  SCREEN-IMAGE.
       05  BLANK SCREEN
           BACKGROUND-COLOR 0.
       05  LINE 02  COLUMN 02          PIC X(8)
               FROM TIME-HHMMSSXX-COLONS
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15.
       05  LINE 02  COLUMN 25
               VALUE 'Purchase Order Line Item Maintenance'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 14.
       05  LINE 02  COLUMN 70          PIC X(8)
               FROM DATE-MMDDYY-SLASHES
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15.
       05  LINE 04  COLUMN 02  VALUE 'FUNCTION CODE:'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 04  COLUMN 18          PIC X(3)
               USING FUNCTION-CODE-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15 AUTO.
       05  LINE 04  COLUMN 23  VALUE '(ADD, CHG, DEL, INQ, END)'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 11.
       05  LINE 07  COLUMN 23  VALUE 'NUMBER:'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 07  COLUMN 50          PIC X(4)
               USING POLI-VEND-NUMBER-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15 AUTO.
       05  LINE 08  COLUMN 23  VALUE 'ORDER ID:'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 08  COLUMN 50          PIC X(8)
               USING POLI-ORDER-ID-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15 AUTO.
       05  LINE 09  COLUMN 23  VALUE 'LINE ITEM:'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 09  COLUMN 50          PIC X(4)
               USING POLI-LINE-ITEM-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15 AUTO.
       05  LINE 10  COLUMN 23  VALUE 'ITEM ID:'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 10  COLUMN 50          PIC X(10)
               USING POLI-ITEM-ID-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15 AUTO.
       05  LINE 11  COLUMN 23  VALUE 'QUANTITY:'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 11  COLUMN 50          PIC X(5)
               USING POLI-QUANTITY-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15 AUTO.
       05  LINE 12  COLUMN 23  VALUE 'DATE REQUESTED (YYYYMMDD):'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 12  COLUMN 50          PIC X(8)
               USING POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15 AUTO.
       05  LINE 13  COLUMN 23  VALUE 'QUOTED COST:'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 13  COLUMN 50          PIC X(7)
               USING POLI-QUOTED-COST-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15 AUTO.
       05  LINE 17  COLUMN 23  VALUE 'DATE ADDED:'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 17  COLUMN 40  PIC X(10)
               USING POLI-DATE-ADDED-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15.
       05  LINE 18  COLUMN 23  VALUE 'DATE-CHANGED:'
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 10.
       05  LINE 18  COLUMN 40  PIC X(10)
               USING POLI-DATE-CHANGED-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 15.
       05  LINE 23  COLUMN 23  PIC X(55)
               FROM ERROR-MESSAGE-S
               FOREGROUND-COLOR 12.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   900-VALIDATE-THE-FIELDS.
       IF POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-1 IS NOT = 20
           MOVE 'Year must be 2011 OR 2012' TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
           GO TO 999-EXIT
       END-IF
       IF POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-2 IS NOT = 11 OR 12
           MOVE 'Year Must Be 2011 Or 2012' TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
           GO TO 999-EXIT
       END-IF
       IF POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-3 IS < 1 OR > 12
           MOVE 'Month Must Be 1 Through 12' TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
           GO TO 999-EXIT
       END-IF
       IF POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-4 IS < 1 OR > 31
           MOVE 'Day Must Be 1 Through 31' TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
           GO TO 999-EXIT
       END-IF.
```

Also, I have to make sure that a record in a field called POLI-ITEM-ID already exists in another indexed file called ITEM-MASTER. I am not exactly sure how to do this, but I assume that it involves temporarily opening the file and searching it. If anyone could show me how to do this I would be grateful, as these two things seem to be the only things holding me back today. I thank everyone for all the help in advance.

Edit: The input data is written on a screen image that is part of the program. Thus I know that what I put in in correct at the time of entry. If it helps, I have put the SCREEN SELECTION in the code, but I do not think it has any bearing on why my date entry is considered an error (i.e. I put in "2011" and it tells me on the screen "Year must be 2011 OR 2012").

Comment: Ignore the humor merchants. But we need to se your input data.

Comment: @Neil All data is input onto a screen before so there is no actual input data. Would it help if put the whole program here?

Comment: I've never done COBOL before, but this strikes me as strange: `IF POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-2 IS NOT = 11 OR 12` Most languages I'm familiar with would parse `foo != 11 or 12` as `(foo != 11) or (12)`. Does COBOL really parse the expression as `foo != (11 or 12)`?

Comment: @sarnold no, I'm afraid not. COBOL relies less on symbols and more on words.

Comment: hah, my question is directly answered [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL#Syntactic_features). It seems very 'friendly' and 'chatty' for a language from 1959. :) Thanks for the education. :)

Comment: Don't be lazy, write the IFs out in full. Costs you very little time when writing, costs a lot of time for anyone (including you) reading the program in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   05  POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S.
       10 POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-1  PIC 9999.
          88 Year-Valid            value 2011 thru 2012.
       10 POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-2  PIC 99.
          88 Month-Valid           value 01 thru 12.
       10 POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-4  PIC 99.              
          88 Day-Valid             value 01 thru 31.
```

Try redefining your fields like this.  Then you can do a simple test of the fields with:

```
  IF not Year-Valid
       MOVE 'Year must be 2011 OR 2012' TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
  Else
       IF not Month-Valid
          MOVE 'Month Must Be 1 Through 12' TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
       Else
          IF not Day-Valid
              MOVE 'Day Must Be 1 Through 31' TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
          END-IF
       END-IF
  END-IF
```

To deal with your lookup, do a direct read on the ITEM-MASTER file.  That will involve something like this:

```
   SELECT ITEM-MASTER ASSIGN TO "fname.txt"
      ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
      ACCESS MODE IS DYNAMIC
      RECORD KEY IS ITEM-MASTER-KEY.
```

and then do a direct read:

```
  READ ITEM-MASTER
     KEY IS POLI-ITEM-ID
     INVALID KEY  DISPLAY "error or something"
  END-READ
```

Comment: What about February, April, June, September and November? They don't have 31 days.

Comment: It's homework...I want to leave SOMETHING for the student to do.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful - the accepted solution does not guarantee numeric values. 
The following program illustrates the point:

```
   PROGRAM-ID. EXAMPLE.                       
   DATA DIVISION.                             
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                   
   01  TXT-VALUE        PIC X(4).             
   01  NUM-VALUE        PIC 9(4).             
       88 WS-VALID-NUM  VALUE  2000 THRU 2999.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.                        
       MOVE '21b1' TO TXT-VALUE               
       MOVE TXT-VALUE TO NUM-VALUE            
       DISPLAY 'NUM-VALUE: ' NUM-VALUE        
       IF WS-VALID-NUM                        
          DISPLAY 'passed the range test.'    
       END-IF                                 
       IF NUM-VALUE IS NUMERIC                
          DISPLAY 'passed numeric test.'      
       ELSE                                   
          DISPLAY 'failed numeric test.'      
       END-IF
```

Which results in the following output:

```
NUM-VALUE: 21b1       
passed the range test.
failed numeric test.
```

Lesson: Always validate numeric fields with an `IS NUMERIC` test and then a range test.

Furthermore, unless input data have been pre-edited for validity, 
it is not a good idea to read external data directly into numeric
data types. Reading '1b' from an
input file directly into a `PIC 9(2)` data item yields the value 12 (in an ebcdic based
environment). This will now pass an `IS NUMERIC` test as well as range tests even though
the actual input data were not numeric. The reasons for the "automatic" conversion are
a bit beyond this discussion - lets just say data movement rules in COBOL are
much more complex than most people appreciate.

Comment: If you read a record which contains fields defined as numeric, nothing will "happen" to those fields before they are referenced. For "external" data, definitely do the NUMERIC test. Things may happen *when* they are referenced, but this depends on compiler option NUMPROC.

Comment: Actually, Neal, it does.  21b1 is a valid zoned value.  Only the high nibble of the terminal "1" matters for the numeric-ness of the number.  The rest are stripped.

Comment: No Joe, not on IBMs. Neither 21b1 nor 21B1 pass the NUMERIC test positively. Both can be "used" in calculations, where the zone is irrelevant, but the zone is entirely relevant for a NUMERIC test.

Answer (score 1):

Joe Zitzelberger's post is the recommended and 'clean' way to do this.

I would just point out that the error in your original code was to mix up XX and numeric types. You should either have used character literals in your tests:

```
IF POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-1 IS NOT = '20'
```

or, better, defined your data values as numbers:

```
 10 POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-1  PIC 99.
```

Comment: Unless there is a *need* to define as numeric (some calculation will be done, or otherwise used in a "numeric" manner (like a numeric-edit) it is always better to define as X. Just because a field contains numbers always, or it has the word NUMBER in its name, does not mean it should be defined as a numeric. An no, Joe's solution is flawed.

Comment: Please, enlighten...in what way is it flawed?  It is fine as a helpful homework example.  If the students want production quality tested code, they give me $250/hour...helpful hints are free.

Answer (score 0):

```
01  FILLER. 
05  POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S. 
    10  POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-1  PIC XXXX. 
        88  YEAR-VALID            VALUE "2011" THRU "2012". 
    10  POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-2  PIC XX. 
        88  MONTH-VALID           VALUE "01" THRU "12". 
        88  MONTH-IS-FEB          VALUE "02". 
        88  MONTH-IS-30-DAYS      VALUE "04" "06" "09" "11".
    10  POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S-4  PIC XX. 
        88  DAY-MAY-BE-VALID      VALUE "01" THRU "31". 
        88  VALID-FEB-DAYS        VALUE "01" THRU "28". 
        88  VALID-30-DAYS         VALUE "01" THRU "30".
```

Then the "first cut", with a student who doesn't have to worry about the actual number of days a month has:

```
MOVE SPACE                   TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
EVALUATE TRUE 
  WHEN NOT POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S NUMERIC 
      MOVE 'DATE MUST ONLY BE NUMBERS' 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
  WHEN NOT YEAR-VALID 
    MOVE 'YEAR MUST BE 2011 OR 2012' 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
  WHEN NOT MONTH-VALID 
    MOVE 'MONTH MUST BE 01 THROUGH 12' 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
  WHEN NOT DAY-MAY-BE-VALID 
    MOVE "DAY IS ZERO OR MORE THAN 31" 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
END-EVALUATE
```

And then amended later for the actual number of days.

```
MOVE SPACE                   TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
EVALUATE TRUE 
  WHEN NOT POLI-DATE-REQUESTED-S NUMERIC 
      MOVE 'DATE MUST ONLY BE NUMBERS' 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
  WHEN NOT YEAR-VALID 
    MOVE 'YEAR MUST BE 2011 OR 2012' 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
  WHEN NOT MONTH-VALID 
    MOVE 'MONTH MUST BE 01 THROUGH 12' 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
  WHEN NOT DAY-MAY-BE-VALID 
    MOVE "DAY IS ZERO OR MORE THAN 31" 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
  WHEN ( MONTH-IS-FEB 
       AND NOT VALID-FEB-DAYS ) 
   MOVE 'TOO MANY DAYS FOR FEBRUARY' 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
  WHEN ( MONTH-IS-30-DAYS 
       AND NOT VALID-30-DAYS ) 
   MOVE 'NO 31ST THIS MONTH' 
                             TO ERROR-MESSAGE-S
END-EVALUATE
```